# How to allow numbers, backspace, delete, left and right arrow keys in the html text?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using following javascript code which I think should only allow numbers, backspace, delet, left arrow and right arrow keys in textbox, but it is also allowing alphabets. I don't know why?

```
function validateQty(event) {
    var key = window.event ? event.keyCode : event.which;

if (event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 46
 || event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 39) {
    return true;
}
else if ( key < 48 || key > 57 ) {
    return false;
}
else return true;
};
```

Calling this function as

```
<input type="text" onkeypress='validateQty(event)'>
```

Comment: What do you mean by ALLOW *backspace*, *delete*, *left* and *right*

Comment: @Mr.Alien - I mean these keys. Edited my question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No doubt your code is correct but you missed "return" keyword in textbox.

```
<input type="text" onkeypress='return validateQty(event);'>
```

You can see the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vLEZY/)

Comment: yes, it works. But problem occurs when I copy paste any alphabet.

Comment: @nkp - if you paste a value without using the keyboard then obviously a `keypress` handler is not going to catch it. If you paste _with_ the keyboard you need to test for that with `keydown`, because I don't think paste triggers a `keypress` event. (Might be simpler to just remove unwanted characters `onblur`...)

Comment: @Learning - yes, that I know. Just wanted to go one step further

Comment: @Learning - If I call same function on onkeydown event, even numeric values are not copied to text.

Comment: @nkp - The comment you seem to be replying to was mine. I didn't say to call the _same_ function on keydown, I just noted that you might need to use keydown in some way if you want to catch a keyboard-based paste. Again, removing unwanted characters on blur might be easier, because users can put text in a field without using the keyboard _or_ the clipboard (using drag'n'drop).

Comment: @nnnnnn you are right. There are many way to put text in textbox.

Comment: @nkp if you want full solution you have to take care of the condition stated by.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text"  class="form-control" id="dompetku_msisdn" name="dompetku_msisdn" placeholder="Phone Number"  aria-describedby="helpBlock" onkeydown='return (event.which >= 48 && event.which <= 57) || event.which == 8 || event.which == 46 || event.which == 37 || event.which == 39' required /> </input>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```js
      function isNumberKey(evt)
      {
         var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
         if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
            return false;
         return true;
      }
```

```html
<HTML>
   <HEAD>
   </HEAD>
   <BODY>
      <input id="txtChar" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" type="text" name="txtChar" maxlength="10">
   </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Please explain what you've written.

Comment: written code is to user allow only numeric, arow key, back press key in text box if you need this type of text box...

Answer (score 0):

```
const validateQty = (event) => {
    var key = window.event ? event.keyCode : event.which;
    console.log(event);
    if (event.keyCode === 8 || event.keyCode === 46
        || event.keyCode === 37 || event.keyCode === 39) {
        return true;
    } else if (key < 48 || key > 57) {
        return false;
    } else { return true; }
};


<input type="text" onkeydown='return validateQty(event);'>
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified his code a bit, so you can just add a class to an input

```
$(".numberonly").keydown(function(e){
    // Number Only
    if (e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46
       || e.keyCode == 37 || e.keyCode == 39) {
          return true;
      }
      else if ( e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57 ) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
  });
```

add class to an input

```
<input type="text" class="numberonly" />
```

Comment: Well, this one does also allow you to type !@#$%^&*() as you are allowing the shift key, and technically you are still pressing the 'number key'