# allow only float number with backspace and left and right arrow

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to allow only one `.` in textfield, with backspace, left and right arrow.

I found this this link.

[only allow numbers, backspace, delet, left arrow and right arrow keys in textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20682707/how-to-allow-numbers-backspace-delete-left-and-right-arrow-keys-in-the-html-t)

I addded one more validation in above code, so that user can add only `.` in textfield, but it's not working.

JS

```
function validateQty(event) {
    var key = window.event ? event.keyCode : event.which;
if (event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 39 ) {
    if($(this).val().indexOf('.') == -1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
else if ( key < 48 || key > 57 ) {
    return false;
}
else return true;
};
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/vLEZY/100/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem as I see it is that in the line `if($(this).val().indexOf('.') == -1)`, the `this` is the Window object not the input control.

Try adding an ID to the input control and reference the same in the code as:

```js
function validateQty(event) {
    var key = window.event ? event.keyCode : event.which;
    if (event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 39 ) {
    if($('#IdofInputControl').val().indexOf('.') == -1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
    }
    else if ( key < 48 || key > 57 ) {
        return false;
    }
        else return true;
    };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" ID="IdofInputControl" onkeypress='return validateQty(event);'>
```

And your validation should work!

Answer (score 1):

function isNumber(evt) {

```
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)&&(evt.which != 46 || $('#refAmount').val().indexOf('.') != -1)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code with some modifications of keys which you want to use or not.

```
jQuery("#YourSelector").keypress(function (evt) { 
     var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;

     if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 43 || charCode > 57)){
        return false;
     }else{ 
        return true;
     }
});
```

Comment: Did you check your code. in you haven't applied validation for doulble `.` and also you are not checking `.` keycode

Comment: @AmitKumar As I have told, you have to do some modifications. I have just given a sample to go through.

Comment: Then You didn't see my question properly. I have already written more code that your answer.